# Drawable not found when use shrinkResources true

Tags: android, proguard, shrinkresources

```
menu_item": [
    {
      "item": "Something",
      "sub_item": [
      ],
      "icon": "ic_something",
      "counter": ""
    }
]
```

Here not found "icon": "ic_something"